# drop down list suggestions limited to particular values

Tags: spotfire

I have a list of group leaders and each group leader has his own team, when a group leader clicks on his name, it leads him to his employees, I wanna make a drop down list so he can select the employee he wants but i dont want the drop down list to show all the employees from all the teams, i only want it to show the employees of that particular group leader.

there is no data limiting possible so i wonder how it is possible to do it, or if it is even possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a reference data table with one column - 'leader'.
2. Create a reference data table with two columns - 'leader' and 'employees'.
3. Create a Document Property ('ldr') based on distinct column values from the 1st data table - which will allow leaders to select their own name.
4. The value of 'ldr' will now be used to filter the data in the 2nd data table, by going to Data Canvas, adding a 'Filter' transformatopm and using a custom expression like this:

   case when DocumentProperty('ldr') = '' then true
   when DocumentProperty('ldr') != '' and DocumentProperty('ldr') = [leader] then true 
   else false end
5. So now your 2nd data table should have only the employees of the selected leader.
6. Create a new drop down Document Property ('emp') based on distinct values in the employee column of the 2nd data table.
7. These two document properties created in the previous steps are just filters which have the appropriate employee values but are not linked to any visualization yet.
8. So to link the filters to the visualizations, go to Visualization properties -> Data -> Limit Data using expression -> Use an expression like:

   [employees] = DocumentProperty('emp')